# SQLite Insert data error

Tags: sqlite

this is my quary.i want to add html text to my data base

```
INSERT INTO minute_item ( meeting_minute_id , type , text , date , responsible , status , finished_date,seq_id, cellHeight) VALUES ("5","Info", "<font face="Arial" size="3"><span style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);">sdfsdfsdfsdfd</span></font>", "(null)","","open","(null)","3","79.000000")
```

it gives this error message.can you please how to solve this error
[image]

Comment: You need to escape your input before inserting

Comment: A string literal is quoted using single quotes `'`, not double, `"`.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, strings use single quotes. (Double quotes are supported in SQLite only for compatibility with MySQL.)
The correct syntax looks like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO minute_item (
    meeting_minute_id, type, text, date, responsible,
    status, finished_date, seq_id, cellHeight)
VALUES (
    '5', 'Info',
    '<font face="Arial" size="3"><span style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);">sdfsdfsdfsdfd</span></font>',
    '(null)', '', 'open', '(null)', '3', '79.000000')
```

If you want to use a single quote inside a string, you have to double it: `'it''s like this'`.
(It would work the same way with double quotes.)

Please note that numbers that you want to store as numbers, not as strings, must not be quoted.